# How can I train my cat to successfully bury her poop

Tags: cats, toilet-training, cat-litter

I have a 19 week old ragdoll kitten. I got her at 3 months from the breeder and she was well trained, good with her litter box and knew to use a scratching post. The exception being that when she tries to bury her poop she will always go to the far edge of the litter box to try and cover it but it's simply too far to reliably work. She will try different angles until it does get buried but every other time she turns back around she ends up stepping in the poop.

The litter box she first had was a small, maybe 9"x12" box. Hoping to aid the issue I quickly got her a 'jumbo' 22"x18" box. It gives her plenty of room but has only made the distance she goes further. My current stance has been to help her bury it with the scooper and hoping that her similar attempts with her pee will teach her but i've not seen progress in a month in a half.

While I've been working on her with more common things like getting used to water, I don't really know how to correct a behavior like this. I'm thinking I might be shooting myself in the foot by helping her but don't want to constantly clean up poop. Where should I start? Should I just be patient while she grows big enough to properly bury at a distance? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Please have a look into [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29808/my-bengal-cat-doesnt-cover-his-feces-and-pees-over-the-edge-of-the-litter-box) (and the accepted answer), and let us know, if the information there solves your problem! :)

Comment: I can try some of the tips. She is trying and will keep trying until it's buried, the problem being more that she is clumsy about it when turning around after checking if it's buried enough.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a way to get them to properly bury their waste, but I do not know of any. It seems to be a very instinctual behavior that they're not even entirely aware of what is it they're trying to accomplish, as my cat will try to bury things in the hardwood floor, which very obviously won't work. He digs at the cover of the litter box too.  I'm really not sure what he's thinking.

However, I do have a suggestion for you, which is to get a large litter box that is very shallow with no cover, and to keep it away from walls. If the cat can easily access the litter box from all directions without having to turn around in the box, perhaps it will change how she walks in the box, and will no longer step in anything. You don't necessarily need to use an actual litter box either. A large Tupperware will do, if you cannot find a box of that shape.

Comment: The problem is rather she turns around to check if it's buried and then back around to keep digging. The problem seems to be more 'clumsy' or not knowing quite where her back paws are during this.